# Liferay instance on server with apache httpd

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, liferay

I am a Java developer who was given a task of running Liferay Portal on a remote server (I do have an IP and root access). The server already has one instance of old Liferay and Apache web server. I would like to setup additional Liferay Portals and access them through `ip:port` running on that server.

How can I run multiple sites on different ports using Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to read up on [VirtualHosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) - roughly you'd have something like the following in your httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName liferay-old.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    #### Server config for 'old' version of Liferay goes here
</VirtualHost>

Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    Server liferay-new.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    #### Server config for 'new' version of Liferay goes here
</VirtualHost>
```